# At a time only one thread is executed, how to execute multiple tasks simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading

Click http://www.javatpoint.com/sleep()-method

It's tutorial said only when a thread is sleep, the another thread will be picked up by thread scheduler. So only one thread is working each time?

Comment: No, who said that?  It just said that when a single thread sleeps, another thread will get chosen to run on that processor.  It doesn't say that there aren't other threads going at the same time.

Comment: Both threads are running, they just sleep for 500ms and output a counter

Comment: @RobertI Why another thread start when the former one sleep? Why not both thread start together?

Comment: This post might help you to understand the concept clearly. [link](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-multithreading/)

Comment: Both will start. When you cann thread.start() it will fork into a thread and the code continues. If you call thread.run() it will block the main thread

Comment: @Varrian this is what happens if there are more threads than processors and they can't _all_ run at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a system with multiple cores, both threads would start at about the same time (depending on how long it takes to create a thread).

The effect of the sleeps could end up "synchronizing" the threads, so that both threads would be running and/or sleeping at the same (or very nearly the same) time (depends on the OS). The "synchronizing" would occur if both threads got started within one system timer tick of each other. For Windows, the timer normally runs at 64hz, or 15.625 ms per tick, so both threads would exit the sleep state every 32 timer ticks (500 ms) on the same tick.

During a sleep, the OS can run other threads on the same core as the thread that did the sleep. In this case, unless the system only has a single core (and no hyperthreading), the two threads run at the same time.

I assume that System.out.println(i) is multi-threaded safe (so that two instances at the same time from two threads doesn't cause a problem).